# Gives me an Error when I Insert data to my Customer table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sql-insert

I am developing a Java Web Restful Application and when I insert data it gives an error something like this..

```
"com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"
```

I cant figure out what is wrong with my SQL syntax

My SQL query looks like this....

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO customer(fname, lname, email, phone, country, dob, city, postal, address1, address2, password, regDate, status) "
            + "VALUES ('"+customer.getFname()+"', '"+customer.getLname()+"', '"+customer.getEmail()+"', '"+customer.getPhone()+"', '"+customer.getCountry()+"',"
                    + "'"+customer.getDob()+"', '"+customer.getCity()+"', '"+customer.getPostal()+"', '"+customer.getAddress1()+"', '"+customer.getAddress2()+"',"
                    + "'"+customer.getPassword()+"', NOW(), 'active'";
```

All the Column Types have '(varchar)' except, 'dob(date)', 'regDate(date)'..

Thank You!

Comment: [You should not try and glue values directly into your SQL](https://xkcd.com/327/). It is error-prone and it is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use a statement that supports separate parameters.

Comment: The prior comment is referring to `PreparedStatement` with placeholders (the question mark, `?`). See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Answer (score 0):

@jacob , you can't pass date object directly  within quotes.Instead You need to format it into String type using DateFormatter.Once you get your date into string type then you can pass that value to column.

One advice : don't use this '','','',... queries..It may face SQL Injection.Instead you use parameterized query so that your query can't be altered.

Comment: Passing a `date` value as a String is a really bad advice

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ,you can upvote my comment ! I told the same thing :-)

Comment: Well you are recommending just that: "*you need to format it into String type*" and "*Once you get your date into string type then you can pass that value to column*".

Answer (score -1):

yes, closing bracket is missing in query

But put escape character for single quote ( ' ) , if data has single quote query will give error

```
 "INSERT INTO customer(fname, lname, email, phone, country, dob, city, postal, address1, address2, password, regDate, status) "
        + "VALUES ('"+escape( customer.getFname() )+"', '"
                 +escape( customer.getLname() ) +"', '"
                 +escape( customer.getEmail() ) +"', '"
                 +escape( customer.getPhone() ) +"', '"
                 +escape( customer.getCountry() )+"',"
                     +"'"+customer.getDob() +"', '"
                     +escape( customer.getCity() ) +"', '"
                     +escape( customer.getPostal() ) +"', '"
                     +escape( customer.getAddress1() ) +"', '"
                     +escape( customer.getAddress2()) +"',"
                    + "'"+escape( customer.getPassword() )+"', NOW(), 'active' )";


public static String escape(String val) {
    return (val==null?null:val.replaceAll("'", "''"));
}
```

Comment: The proper way is to use prepared statement with parameters, not trying to quote values yourself.